# difference between novelty, concept drift and anomaly

Tags: data-mining, terminology

Concept drift is when the relation between the input
data and the target variable changes over time. like changes in the conditional distribution.

is novelty an outlier? what should I think of?
what is the difference between concept drift and novelty and anomaly?
is the concept drift considered a type of novelty? how exactly? can you please explain !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly all three concepts are related.

**Drift** means the relationship between input and output is dynamic and changes (stochastically) over (sufficiently long periods of) time. That is, it is **not stationary**. For example, consumers' criteria about what to buy, change over time, for example as people become more eco-conscious. More importantly drift, when it happens, **invalidates the existing model used for prediction**.

**Anomaly** also called an **outlier** is a very rare non-typical event (when input-output relationship is considered stationary over time), that happens upon exceptional circumstances. Something like a white snake. It may happen but is not typical of snakes and if it happens it does not mean that input-output relationship has necessarily drifted from the original assumptions (eg the assumptions about the color distribution of snakes). Accordingly anomaly, when it happens, **does not invalidate the existing model used for prediction**.

**Novelty** as far as I understand it, is an umbrella term for something new and unpredictable happening, which however may be attributable to anything (drift, anomaly, etc).

**Please note** that determining the reason for the observed novelty requires careful analysis (for example, multiple anomalies may mean drift is what is actually happening)!

References:

1. [Anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection)
2. [Concept drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift)

Comment: thanks for your fully explained answer but what about novelty does it also invalidates the existing model used for prediction? and can I think of the concept as a type of novelty? under what conditions?

Comment: Novelty term, per this answer can mean any unpredictable event, including drift. So yes drift is a type of novelty. Whether novelty invalidates the model depends on the type of novelty, an outlier novelty, does not invalidate the model.

Comment: in this case how to make the model adapt to such change whether it's novelty type or concept drift?

Comment: This is the holy grail of machine learning. There is not clear cut answer, only some approaches that might work in some cases. Read the references.